# The loss function decreases, but the test accuracy is always 0.5

Tags: pennylane

```
def layer(W):
    for i in range(wires1):
        qml.Rot(W[i, 0], W[i, 1], W[i, 2], wires=i)
    for i in range(wires1 - 1):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[i, i + 1])


@qml.qnode(dev1)   
def conv_net(features, para):
    """
    qml.MottonenStatePreparation(state_vector=Norm1DArray(features), wires=range(wires1))
    qml.adjoint(convolutional_layer)(para[:63])
    qml.CNOT(wires=[0, 3])
    qml.CNOT(wires=[1, 4])
    qml.CNOT(wires=[2, 5])
    """
    #qml.CRY(para[0], wires=[3, 4])
    #qml.CRY(para[1], wires=[4, 5])
    #qml.CRY(para[2], wires=[5, 3])
    """    
    qml.CRY(para[63], wires=[3, 4])
    qml.CRY(para[64], wires=[4, 5])
    qml.CRY(para[65], wires=[5, 3])
    """
    qml.MottonenStatePreparation(state_vector=Norm1DArray(features), wires=range(wires1))
    for W in para:
        layer(W)

    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(5))

def variational_classifier(para, bias, features):
    return conv_net(features, para) + bias

def cost(para, bias, features, labels):
    predictions = [variational_classifier(para, bias, f) for f in features]
    return square_loss(labels, predictions)

digits = datasets.load_digits()
features, labels = digits.data, digits.target

# only use first two classes
features = features[np.where((labels == 0) | (labels == 1))]
labels = labels[np.where((labels == 0) | (labels == 1))]

num_train = int(0.75 * len(labels))
num_test = len(labels) - num_train

# normalize data
features = features / np.linalg.norm(features, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
index = np.random.permutation(range(len(labels)))
print(index)

x_train = features[index[:num_train]]
y_train = labels[index[:num_train]]
x_test = features[index[num_train:]]
y_test = labels[index[num_train:]]
print(x_train, x_train.shape)
print(y_train, y_train.shape)
print(x_test, x_test.shape)
print(y_test, y_test.shape)

opt = qml.NesterovMomentumOptimizer(0.05)
batch_size = 5

# train the variational classifier
weights = para_init
bias = bias_init

for it in range(max_iterations):

    # Update the weights by one optimizer step
    batch_index = np.random.randint(0, num_train, (batch_size,))
    x_train_batch = x_train[batch_index]
    y_train_batch = y_train[batch_index]
    weights, bias, _, _ = opt.step(cost, weights, bias, x_train_batch, y_train_batch)
    #print(weights)

    # Compute predictions on train and validation set
    predictions_train = [np.sign(variational_classifier(weights, bias, f)) for f in x_train]
    predictions_val = [np.sign(variational_classifier(weights, bias, f)) for f in x_test]

    # Compute accuracy on train and validation set
    acc_train = accuracy(y_train, predictions_train)
    acc_val = accuracy(y_test, predictions_val)

    print( "Iter: {:5d} | Cost: {:0.7f} | Acc train: {:0.7f} | Acc validation: {:0.7f} " 
          "".format(it + 1, cost(weights, bias, features, labels), acc_train, acc_val))

Iter: 1 | Cost: 0.2924991 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 2 | Cost: 0.2882189 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 3 | Cost: 0.2817786 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 4 | Cost: 0.2812447 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 5 | Cost: 0.2809657 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 6 | Cost: 0.3025342 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 7 | Cost: 0.3086777 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 8 | Cost: 0.3035319 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 9 | Cost: 0.3161824 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 10 | Cost: 0.3167217 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 11 | Cost: 0.3173991 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 12 | Cost: 0.3274824 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 13 | Cost: 0.3235402 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 14 | Cost: 0.3237779 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 15 | Cost: 0.3283499 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 16 | Cost: 0.3373461 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 17 | Cost: 0.3376850 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 18 | Cost: 0.3380883 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 19 | Cost: 0.3362846 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 20 | Cost: 0.3341627 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 21 | Cost: 0.3362121 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 22 | Cost: 0.3398094 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 23 | Cost: 0.3462145 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 24 | Cost: 0.3541274 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 25 | Cost: 0.3497878 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 26 | Cost: 0.3574255 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 27 | Cost: 0.3494558 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 28 | Cost: 0.3309330 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 29 | Cost: 0.3135182 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 30 | Cost: 0.3191676 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 31 | Cost: 0.3242883 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 32 | Cost: 0.3209517 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 33 | Cost: 0.3245124 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 34 | Cost: 0.3203839 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 35 | Cost: 0.3238435 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 36 | Cost: 0.3222851 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 37 | Cost: 0.3225848 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 38 | Cost: 0.3254254 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 39 | Cost: 0.3240605 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 40 | Cost: 0.3343621 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 41 | Cost: 0.3347087 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
Iter: 42 | Cost: 0.3311704 | Acc train: 0.5037037 | Acc validation: 0.5111111
```

https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_variational_classifier.html

I use the reference case: Variational classifier — PennyLane documentation for the binary classification of 0 and 1 in MNIST. And tried different Ansatz and optimizers, the result is that the loss function drops, but the test accuracy and training accuracy are always around 0.5. How to solve it?